# Synonym for table stakes in a business context?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

I dislike 'table stakes' to describe the bare essentials. Looking for a better way to describe it. For example:

> Email and SaaS applications are just table stakes. Custom enterprise software gives your business a sustainable competitive advantage

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for a synonym or a new analogy?  Your current example is drawing a connection, although a sort of weak one, between the gambling entry fee and the advantage at the table. There might be room for "commuter train" vs "express route with your own station" or something that direction.

Comment: What would have been wrong with 'Email and SaaS applications are just the bare essentials?

If you do like 'table stakes' what would be wrong with 'Email and SaaS applications are just table stakes. Custom enterprise software allows your business to up the ante'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about **cost of entry**?

Macmillan:

> [**cost of
>   entry**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/cost-of-entry):
>   the cost of beginning to trade in a particular market for the first
>   time

Your example:

> Being able to provide email and SaaS applications is just the **cost
>   of entry**. Custom enterprise software gives your business a
>   sustainable competitive advantage.

Answer (score 1):

points of parity is another way of stating it, however, it's longer. Also depends on your audience and if they're aware of the term.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding some citations and quoting relevant portions of it here. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Email and SaaS applications are just *commodities*.

This is often used in our business (IT consultancy, specializing in custom-made software solutions). It fits definition 1c of [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commodity):

> a mass-produced unspecialized product

While those kind of software isn't mass-produced, it *is* 'mass-consumed'.

Answer (score 0):

If you perspective if from the product development side perhaps MVP.

Email and SaaS applications comprise **the Minimum Viable Product (MVP)**. Custom enterprise software gives your business a sustainable competitive advantage.*

> In product development, **the Minimum Viable Product (MVP)** is a product with just enough features to gather validated learning about the product and its continued development. Gathering insights from an MVP is often less expensive than developing a product with more features, which increase costs and risk if the product fails, for example, due to incorrect assumptions. The term was coined and defined by Frank Robinson, and popularized by Steve Blank, and Eric Ries. It may also involve carrying out market analysis beforehand
>   — [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_product)

Not sure if this is less jarring than *table stakes* but I am hearing it more and more.

Comment: Thanks but the creation aspect (of an MVP) applies to the second half. The first half, generic off-the-shelf/prebuilt things that are table stakes, is what I was looking at

Answer (score 0):

That's the common but inaccurate definition of table stakes, but let's not dwell on that aspect. For bare essentials, I quite like "price of entry" or "cost of entry" though that can imply that once you're in the cinema you're done, rather than all set to compete in the marathon or whatever. "Commodity" is a good one too, but I'd like to suggest a term I have been hearing more often: "hygiene factor" which intuitively makes sense and refers to a theory (Herzberg, 1964) about worker satisfaction but basically about the bare minimum which if absent would be a negative, but not a factor in actually causing happiness or any other appropriate positive

Comment: What do they all mean? Please include definitions!